# How to implement over scrolling

Tags: android

I want to refresh my view when pull down like facebook app(Over scroll).I have a relative layout containing list of webviews.How can i drag this view?Anybody help me please...

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Code Writing, Tutorial or Consulting Service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172496)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [this library](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh) which implements overscroll refreshing for a `ListView`. If a `ListView` doesn't work for you, you could look at the source code for it to see how it's implemented and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Alternatively I'd have a look at [Chris Banes' implementation](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh), which is loosely based on above referenced, but much more up to date and versatile, and - in my experience - it has a better performance. His pull-to-refresh is also available for `GridView` and `WebView` - simply take a look at the included samples.